# Moving Applications Between Multiple Displays

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop with Intel HD graphics and three displays: 1) The laptop, 2) mini HDMI connection to external monitor, 3) USB3 video adapter connected via HDMI to external monitor. All three displays work normally except...
Sometimes I seem to type a special key combination that makes the next number that I type move the active window application to the display with the corresponding index. i.e. hitting a 2 moves the current application to the second display. A 3 moves to third etc.

I cannot figure this key combination out or where to turn it off. It's driving me nuts!!!

Comment: Honestly, Your description of the problem isn't clear enough.  I know of non Windows command that would be left enabled, after being pressed, that would continue to change the display of the active application window.

Comment: I don't believe Windows has in inbuilt shortcut like you're describing, so it's probably a 3rd party utility. Reboot in Safe Mode, and/or disable all non-MS start-ups and services, and see if the problem stops.

Comment: I agree with @Techie007, this will be a third party application. Most laptops come with pre-installed applications that do this sort of thing. What is the make/model of your laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Users on this post reported the same problem, so check to see if you are running "Super Utility":

[Keyboard shortcut to move a window between two monitors instead of drag and drop.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-between-two/7288c458-cbb6-4231-8772-28be60f0a627)

> I had a similar issue. A window would jump to a different monitor as I
>   typed unexpectedly. The issue started shortly after I installed a "J5
>   Create" USB 3.0 VGA adapter, model JUA310. Their software installed
>   "Super Utility". It assigned three hotkeys for the three monitors to
>   move the active window to a different monitor, Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, and
>   Ctrl+3. I resolved the issue by disabling the hotkeys via the "Super
>   Utility". Here is a procedure.
>
> In the Windows 7 tray, right click on "Super Utility" and select
>   "Multi-Display Control Panel". The "Multi-Display Control Panel" is
>   displayed. Select the "Disable" button. Select the "Save/Exit" button.

Comment: I think you may have cracked it. I am also using a J5 Create USB 3.0 VGA adapter. I don't have the Super Utility installed, just the driver. But that might be part of my problem also. Will report when this resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the J5 Create driver from version 14.x to the latest version 15.01.0128 and have not experienced the problem again. I did not install the Super Utility software.